# How to permanently hide menu item?

Tags: html, css

I've got two menu items that keep popping up intermittently, despite having hidden them. One, `contact`, the other a search bar.

To deal with the first one in this case.

How can I keep it permanently hidden?

I've tried `display: none;` but it still shows up and I'm assuming if display: none hides it sometimes, visibility: hidden, isn't going to have a more specific effect.

```css
.menu-item-3530 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
</div>
<div class="module-group 
    right">
  <div class="module 
    left">
    <div class="collapse 
    navbar-collapse navbar-ex1- 
    collapse">
      <ul id="menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu- 
    item-3530" class="menu-item 
    menu-item-type-post_type 
    menu-item-object-page menu- 
    item-has-children menu- 
    item-3530 dropdown"><a title="Contact" href="https://4309.co.uk
    /contact/">Contact </a>.
          <span class="dropdown- 
    toggle shapely-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><i 
    class="fa fa-angle-down" 
    aria-hidden="true"></i>. 
    </span>
          <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
```

[Here](https://4309.co.uk) is the website.

Comment: Clearly something is overriding your CSS. You need to track it down

Comment: Please don't edit this poor initial `html` structure. That's the reason of the problem

Comment: I was on your page and couln't find the CSS style applied.

Comment: @Pauli_D what could it be?

Comment: @Krupse. Ok. Let me double check but I'm pretty sure it's applied. But why would it show up intermittently even if its not applied? Something must be instructing it to show up intermittently. What? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware to the structure of your code. You have line breaks at the declaration of your classes in `html`.

Using `.menu-item-3530` you will be able to interact with an element like:

```html
<li class="menu-item-3530" ...
```

But not with:

```html
<li class="menu
-item-3530" ...
```

So please correct your `html` structure:

```css
.menu-item-3530 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="module-group right">
  <div class="module left">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul id="menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-3530" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type 
menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3530 dropdown">
          <a title="Contact" href="https://4309.co.uk/contact/">Contact </a>.
          <span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>.
          </span>
          <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
```

Comment: Looks like the line breaks have been fixed in the question, so your answer is now out of date.

Comment: @levininja I rollbacked the edit -> It was the problem of the code here

Comment: @johannchopin my html structure is dirived

Comment: @Amg Sorry what do you mean by that ?

Comment: @johannchopin. My html structure is derived from my php. But that's the thing, fa-angle down doesn't show up in my `header.php` but does show up in my html. I'm not to good with php so wouldn't know how to edit it. If I used css`. li class="menu
-item-3530" {foo}` could i do that to target it and would it make it more specific? Thanks.

Comment: @Amg In this case please update the code where you generate the `html` because it is invalid :/ You can still try to target the element but it would stay a really really bad practice

Comment: @johannchopin. So the thing is that `menu-item-3530 is connect to `fa-angle-down. It's the top item in my WordPress menu. WordPress seem to specify that you have a header menu item and I'm trying to get around this by hiding it. (menu-item-3530). The thing is that hiding menu-item-3530, means hiding fa-angle - down, a key intermittent stage in getting to my actual dropdown menu. I'd like, ideally, to get rid of this stage altogether, so that the menu drops straight from bars to the actual menu, with the intermittent contact stage and fa-angle-down removed altogether. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: So if i unhide it, contact shows up intermittently again, and fa-angle down (intermittent menu stage) is still there. If i hide it, you can't access the menu at all, but menu-item-3530 disappears (intermittently) along with fa angle down (the only button which let's me access the menu from front end.